# R for loop to display mean and max of each row in a matrix

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, format

I am trying to create a for loop in R that will display the mean and max for each row in a matrix. Thus far I have:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(matrix_data)) {
   row_means[i] <- mean(matrix_data[i, ])
}
{
max_values_matrix_data [i] <- max(matrix_data [i, ])
}

Mean <- row_means
Max <- max_values_matrix_data
```

If I print Mean and Max I get a string of numbers (13 for each), but the assignment calls for the output to be formatted as:

Row: 1
Mean: 131.26
Max: 200

and so on for 13 rows.

Comment: Try something like `cat(paste("Row:", seq(nrow(matrix_data)), "Mean:", rowMeans(matrix_data), "Max:", apply(matrix_data, 1, max), collapse = "\n"))`.

Comment: Thanks! Part of the assignment was to search for answers (we actually haven't covered loops yet) and I've read that this is a helpful community. Much appreciated, zephryl.

Comment: use `matrixStats::rowMaxs(as.matrix(matrix_data))` and `rowMeans(matrix_data)`

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot as well. I'm just getting started, so finding that there are many ways to come at a problem is very helpful.

Comment: No problem. Note that although loops have their place, a key feature of R is that many functions are *vectorized*, and it’s often easier and more performant to use vectorized operations than loops. Using `rowMeans(matrix_data)` rather than `for (i in 1:nrow(matrix_data)) { row_means[i] <- mean(matrix_data[i, ]) }` is a good example.